# Slow socket performance in .NET - any tips?

Tags: .net, vb.net, performance, sockets, tcp

I am having some performance issues using TCP Sockets in .NET. My application sends files solely in the local network.
If I run my code on localhost, the performance is great (fullspeed - about 250 Mbyte/sec on SSD).
But when I try to send large data in my local gigabit network between different devices, the speed is only around 2-4 Mbyte/sec.

I tried to optimize the buffer size (also set Receive- and Sendbuffersize on both sides), but that didn't help much. Here is the important part of the code:

Receiving:

```
'f contains the file path
'client = listener.AcceptTCPClient...
client.ReceiveBufferSize = RECSENDBUFFSIZE
client.SendBufferSize = RECSENDBUFFSIZE
Dim stream As IO.Stream = client.GetStream()

Dim buffer(BLOCKSIZE - 1) As Byte
Dim fstream As New IO.FileStream(f, FileMode.Open)
Dim flen As ULong = fstream.Length
While fstream.Position < fstream.Length
    Dim count As Integer = fstream.Read(buffer, 0, BLOCKSIZE)
    stream.Write(buffer, 0, count)
End While
fstream.Close()
```

Sending:

```
'f contains the file path
client.Connect(_address, PORT)
stream = client.GetStream
client.ReceiveBufferSize = RECSENDBUFFSIZE
client.SendBufferSize = RECSENDBUFFSIZE

Dim target As String = IO.Path.Combine(MAINFOLDER, f)
Dim fstream As New IO.FileStream(target, FileMode.Create)
Dim buffer(BLOCKSIZE - 1) As Byte
Dim flen As ULong = filesizes(i)
Do
    'I use the min function because there are many files that are transmitted in one connection
    Dim count As Integer = stream.Read(buffer, 0, Math.Min(flen, BLOCKSIZE))
    If count = 0 Then 'some error handling...
    fstream.Write(buffer, 0, count)
    flen -= count
    If flen = 0 Then Exit Do
Loop
fstream.Close()
```

Surprisingly the absolute data throughput increased by having parallel connections to different clients.
I'm already thinking of the implementation of multiple TCP-streams but fear that the costs of synchronization are so high that it won't make a difference.

Do you have any performance tips? Thank you.

Comment: What is the value of `BLOCKSIZE`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. For testing purposes, I chose values between 1024 und 131072.

Comment: Copy a large file between the two hosts to confirm that you get the expected throughput.  If it's slow, then it is something in the network (which starts with the network drivers on each system), not necessarily in your code (your code may have problems, also, but if there is a network problem you need to fix that to see how your code performs).

Comment: You do realise that comparing localhost and your local network makes no sense at all. For localhost nothing is put on the wire, the network driver is not even adressed.

Comment: Thank you. I tried localhost because I wasn't sure if the CPU-load was the limiting factor. Of course it wasn't, but I was desperately searching for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the wrong things. You should not compare the speed of localhost with that of a real network access. When you use TCP for localhost, the only layers that are really used is TCP and IP. IP detects that everything is local and goes immediately back to TCP, without any flow control. When the actual network layers are involved there is bound to be flow control in one of the other network layers or the driver.

What you should really compare your speed with is the speed of your local network. That is a bit tricky but this might help :
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/test-home-network-speed-decipher-results/

The speed of a network is usually depicted in Mbps that is megabit per second.
On the site above there is a dialog for a local network that yields 17 Mbps, you had 2-4 * 8 = 16-32 Mbps without taking the overhead of TCP into account.

But you should run a test on your local network performance and compare with that instead of with localhost.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try to run some tests using the tool presented in the article in the next days. Maybe I blamed the wrong things.